# return viewmodel as a model from controller to view and geting with angularjs and show in option tag in Asp.Net Core 3.1?

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-core

I have code in view like this :

```
$scope.Fields = [];
$scope.showform = function (id) {
    $http.get("/GetCategoryNameById?catid=" + id)
        .then(function (response) {
           
            $scope.Fields = response.data;
            

        });

}
```

and at controller :

```
 public IActionResult GetCategoryNameById(AdvertComplexViewModel fieldslist, int catid)
    {           

        var category = _scopeContext.GetCategoryName(catid);
        fieldslist.CategoryFieldsList = _advert.ShowCategoryFields(catid);

        return Ok($"{fieldslist.CategoryFieldsList}");
    }
```

ViewModel :

```
public class AdvertComplexViewModel
{     

    public IEnumerable<CategoryField> CategoryFieldsList { get; set; }
}
```

this is my Query :

```
 public List<CategoryField> ShowCategoryFields(int id)
    {
        return _context.CategoryFields.Where(c => c.CategoryId == 
        id).ToList();
    }
```

so I want to passing 'category' and 'fieldslist.CategoryFieldsList' as model to view and displaying in Option tags?
how can do this?

Comment: Hi @AliKhansari,Could you please share the model design?And what is the result of your category and fieldslist.CategoryFieldsList?

Comment: category resualt is just Displaying category name and `fieldslist.CategoryFieldsList` for dispaly fields in the same category....so I edited my question and add viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple demo about how to display data to option tag:

View:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Home">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="showform()">Create Account</button>

    <select name="Category">
        <option value="undefined">Please select Value</option>
        <option ng-repeat="option in Fields" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option>
    </select>       
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('Home', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.Fields = [];

        $scope.showform  = function (id) {

            $http.get("/GetCategoryNameById?catid=" + id)
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.Fields = response.data;

                    console.log($scope.Fields);
                });
        };
               
    });       
</script>
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult GetCategoryNameById(int catid)
{

    var category = new AdvertComplexViewModel()
    {
        CategoryFieldsList = new List<CategoryField>()
        {
            new CategoryField(){Id=1,Name="aaa"},
            new CategoryField(){Id=2,Name="bbb"},
            new CategoryField(){Id=3,Name="ccc"}
        }
    };

    return Ok(category.CategoryFieldsList);
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Hi,you have `$scope.showform` in your angularjs,so you need a button to trigger it.You need click the button to call the backend api to display the data.

Comment: I have a button and an ID is sent to the controller.When I use the `{{Fields}}` variable this error is shown `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ComputerShop.DataLayer.Entities.CategoryField]`

Comment: Please set breakpoint to check if backend have data..Or you could add `console.log($scope.Fields);` after `$scope.Fields = response.data;` to check the data from api.

Comment: What?In your model it is type of `IEnumerable<CategoryField>`.Please share the `console.log($scope.Fields);` in your browser.

Comment: show this in console
`System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ComputerShop.DataLayer.Entities.CategoryField]`

Comment: Please share more code to us.Otherwise we can't reproduce your issue.In my case,it works well.

Comment: yes you are right but I don't know why showing ng-repeat as a comment in view?

`<!-- ngRepeat: option in Fields -->`

Comment: If `Fields` has no data,it will display this.

Comment: I set breakpoint and `return Ok($"{fieldslist.CategoryFieldsList}");`  has  amounts

Comment: If have value,please check this line:`<option ng-repeat="option in Fields" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option>`Not sure what is your property name,but the fomat of the property name here should be **camel case**.For example,if you have `ID` in your model,you need use `option.id`,if you have `UserName` in your model,you need use `option.userName`.

Comment: I checked but it's not work for me because I have two tables an relation between that

Comment: Ok.I think you need share more code to use.Otherwise we can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: I changed my questions and completed it

Comment: Hi @AliKhansari,I think you need share screenshot about the backend return data and  share the frontend console panel about this data:`console.log($scope.Fields);`.BTW,did you still make dropdownlist populate with data?

Comment: I said before that it shows  this error
`System.Collections.Generic.List1[ComputerShop.DataLayer.Entities.CategoryField]`